# Split a big array of x elements into y arrays with +/- 1 elements

Tags: java, arrays, modulo

Iam trying to split a array of 5163 elements into 128 arrays, each array should not contains more than +/- 1 element of the average.

5163 / 128 = 40,33, rounded = 40. 5163 % 128 = 43, that indicates that 43 of 128 arrays should contain 1 more than the average.

How can I write this in code ?

```
String [] words; // Contains 5163 words

for(... .. .. .) {

....

}
```

Comment: Please tag homework appropriately.

Comment: @SahilMuthoo:  How can you be so certain this is a homework question?  It could be a general question that's not related to academia; someone learning the language.  You'd have to ask to be sure.

Comment: This is not homework, but a part of a hobby project to learn programming

Comment: If you want to evenly distribute the 41-element arrays among the 128, then you need to position them at each index that is the closest integer above a multiple of 128/43: (0,3,6,9,...,126).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a collection to hold all of the arrays in, perform the division of elements in concordance with your constraints, then return the collection.

I would say that some number of arrays (some random 44 arrays, perhaps) would be getting an extra element in them after the division is done.